# Strange error when compiling iPad application(ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$)

Tags: objective-c, ios

when i compile my project, i have this error :

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_DNCloseButton in /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/...Objects-normal/i386/DNCloseButton-7045D069F03DAA13.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang++ failed with exit code 1
```

I know that the problem is about the class `DNCloseButton` but i don't how to solve it ? thanks for your answers.

Comment: `DNCloseButton` class seems to be duplicated. Search for it in your project

Comment: did you have more than one DNCloseButton interface declarations?

Comment: Mouh Ali, how did you solved it? if you can help others then why don't you post your solution here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure you've only declared the interface once, in a header file (.h), and imported that header file with `#import` and not `#include`.

Sometimes XCode cocks up a little bit and links the same file twice at the linker stage. To fi this:

- Remove the file from your project (select the 'remove references' option) and then add it again.
- Clean with shift-cmd-k
- Build

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

This will happen if a source file is include twice in your Compile Sources Build Phase.

To check this in Xcode 4:

- Select your Project from the file list.
- Select your target from the left column.
- Click on the Build Phases tab on the top bar.
- In the search field, type in the name of the class that is causing the linker error. In the case of the question above, it is DNCloseButton (ignore the preceding _).

If the source file for the class appears twice in the Compile Sources list, delete one of the entries.

Answer (score 5):

You might also get this error if you by accident `#import` the `.m` file instead of the `.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen in the following cases.

You have put the same class implementation into two different files;

You actually have just one implementation of this class, however you are also linking in your project a framework or library containing a class whose name is exactly the same of yours.

Try finding in the whole project your class and make sure only one copy is available within your project.